# Python read multiple columns with Year condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .xlsx file contains Students data - First Name , Last Name, Date of Birth , Class, Major, Minor

I want to list student's first name, last name and DOB where DOB.Year=1990
**
My code  **-

```
stud_dtl=stud_dataset.parse('Students')

stud_dtl_name =stud_dtl[['FirstName','LastName']]
print (stud_name.iloc[101:200])
col = (stud_dtl['DateOfBirth'].dt.year==1990).any()
stud_dtl=stud_dtl.loc[:,col] ### this is going wrong
```

**
please help me with it **

Im sure I have to use loc or iloc but not getting what is wrong
I have calculated the condition want to get data as per that condition

Comment: In your question, can you add what your data frame looks like?

Comment: could you write what the error message say?

Answer (score 0):

probably instead of use

```
col = (stud_dtl['DateOfBirth'].dt.year==1990).any()
```

you need to use

```
col = stud_dtl(stud_dtl['DateOfBirth'].dt.year==1990).any()
```